# Как убрать одновременную загрузку данных со всех вкладок?

Tags: javascript, html

Проблема на сайте вот с этой страницей

> oteli-kryma.ru/oteli_kryma

При загрузке страницы подгружаются данные не только первой вкладки, а всех вкладок.
Использована технология `Bootstrap Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs` от сюда

> www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Нужно чтобы содержимое остальных вкладок не подгружалось, пока не будет нажата нужная вкладка.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить вопрос. Заранее спасибо, с уважением.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<div id="topoteleykryma" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">Топ популярных отелей Крыма по категориям и звездам</h2>

       <div class="container" style="margin:0px auto; padding:0px;">
  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Популярные</a></li>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">1 звезда</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">2 звезды</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">3 звезды</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">4 звезды</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">5 звезд</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">Близко к центру</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu7">Дешевые - Дорогие</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu8">С животными</a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu9">Роскошные</a></li>
  </ul>
<script charset="utf-8" src="//www.travelpayouts.com/widgets/f3c108b2a15b473d1b2ab490c5714683.js?v=772" async></script>

  <div class="tab-content">
      
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3 style="text-align:center">Самые популярные и рейтинговые отели Республики Крым</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=tophotels%2Crating&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели <span class="glyphicon glyphicon">★</span>звезда</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=1stars%2C1stars%2C1stars&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели <span class="glyphicon glyphicon">★★</span>звезды</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=2stars%2C2stars%2C3stars&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели <span class="glyphicon glyphicon">★★★</span>звезды</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=3stars%2C3stars%2C3stars&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели <span class="glyphicon glyphicon">★★★★</span> звезды</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=4stars%2C4stars%2C4stars&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon">★★★★★</span>звезд<h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=5stars%2C5stars%2C5stars&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu6" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Близко к центру Адлера</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=distance%2Cdistance%2Ccenter&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu7" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Дешевые и дорогие отели Адлера</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=price%2Chighprice&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
     <div id="menu8" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Отели, в которых разрешено жить с животными</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=pets&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
    </div>
  
    <div id="menu9" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Самые популярные и рейтинговые отели города Крыма</h3>
      <p><script async src="//www.travelpayouts.com/blissey/scripts.js?categories=luxury%2Cpool%2Csea_view&id=1467199&type=compact&currency=rub&host=search.oteli-kryma.ru%2Fhotels&marker=87111.&limit=40" charset="UTF-8"></script></p>
  
</div>
      </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте необходимые скрипты и разметку непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: Вставил код в сообщение

Comment: в коде из вопроса все вкладки прописаны в разметке сразу они не подгружаются

Comment: Сейчас свой вариант в код добавлю

Comment: Добавил свои данные

Comment: ох-ох-ох, а у этого сайта есть другой апи? чтобы был обычный запрос который бы возвращал данные?

Comment: Нет, только этот